# Задача о кратчайшем пути

Tags: c, графы

Классическая задача, помогите найти подходы к ней

> Имеется N населенных пунктов , пронумерованных от 1 до N. Некоторые пары пунктов соединены дорогами. вывести самый короткий путь из L-го пункта в M-й. Информация о дорогах задается в виде последовательности пар чисел i и j (i < j), указывающих, что i-й и j-й пункты соединены дорогой, признак конца этой последовательности - пара нулей.

Comment: Спросите у ChatGPT. Если он не решит задачу то по крайней мере укажет направление куда смотреть.  Попробуйте сами продолжить.  Что не получится спрашивайте. На этом сайте не решают задачи. А помогают решить трудности возникшие при решении задачи.

Comment: старый добрый Дейкстра

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyQSgTytc4s

Answer (score 1):

решите в лоб для начала

1. начните двигаться от L-го пункта во все возможные пункты
2. каждый шаг вычисляйте пройденное расстояние (в L-ом пункте оно будет 0)
3. запоминайте каждый вычисленный путь в массив (в виде пунктов которые прошли, например [7,5,11,6]
4. если в каком-то пункте вы ранее уже были и расстояние до него меньше, чем текущее, то текущую ветку не продолжайте - она гарантированно будет хуже
5. каждый рассмотренный пункт помечайте как пройденный (чтоб не закольцовывать маршруты)

в конечном итоге у вас останется оптимальный (кратчайший путь)

ну и еще это можно сделать рекурсивно, но лучше итерационно - это не так стек перегружает, а скорость работы схожая плюс-минус

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно здравый подход к задаче(в рамках обучения) - алгоритм Дейкстры, он самый простой, как по мне(если исключить полный перебор). Я его весь в ответе расписывать не смогу и не буду, поэтому приложу материалы, по которым сам учился

1. [Спасибо, Михаил Николаевич](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyQSgTytc4s) - видео на ютубе отличного учёного и преподавателя из НИУ МЭИ. Тут всё будет понятно с первого раза
2. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)
3. [Формальное определение задачи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8)
4. [Другие алгоритмы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B)